# How can i exceute javascript in a frame?

Tags: javascript, frame

I am trying to write javascript code in a frame tag. But it is not excuting my block of javascript code.

The way i am doing this is :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My HomePage</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET id="frameset1" rows="0,100%,0,0,0" frameborder=0>

<FRAME NAME="seat" SRC="seat/seat.html" frameborder="no" border=0  MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="no" NORESIZE>
<FRAME id="main" NAME="main" SRC="main.html" frameborder="no" border=0  MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="no" NORESIZE>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var myVar=1;
</script>

</FRAME>
<FRAME id="seatinfo" NAME="seatinfo" SRC="seatapi/seatinfo/seat_state.html" frameborder="no" border=0  MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="no" NORESIZE>
<FRAME id="blank" NAME="blank" SRC="blank.html" frameborder="no" border=0  MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="no" NORESIZE>   
<FRAME id="preloadHelp" NAME="preloadHelp" SRC="preloadHelp.html" frameborder="no" border=0  MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="no" NORESIZE>
```

When i inspect top.main.myVar in firebug, it displays undefined.

Comment: The `<frame>` and `<frameset>` elements are no longer supported in HTML 5, use `<iframe>`. Also, I don't believe communication between the parent page and its frames is possible, for security reasons.

Comment: @animuson: I'm pretty sure it's possible if they're on the same domain.

Comment: @icktoofay Can you let me know, how i can make it work ?? Thanks.

Comment: how do you intend to use myVar? you should have defined on main.html not inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, look into javascript calls to [document.frames](http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=js+frames&parent=js+frames+and+windows) (or `parent.frame` in the case of working within a frame).

That being said frames are bad practice, IMHO.  I would strongly encourage you to not use them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing code directly in frame tag, you can evaluate your code in target frame, something like next

```
<FRAME id="main" NAME="main" SRC="main.html" frameborder="no" border=0  MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="no" NORESIZE></FRAME>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.frames.main.setTimeout(function(){
        // this code will run in the frame
        window.myVar=1; 
    },1);
</script>
```

in such case myVar will be available in the target document.